# Compress images from clipboard

Tags: python, image, file, compression, clipboard

I want to compress images from the clipboard and put them back, but when i convert them to bmp format, size of the image increases.

```
def set_clipboard_image(img_str):
    bmp_data = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(img_str))
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(bmp_data))
    output = BytesIO()
    image.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
    bmp_data = output.getvalue()[14:]
    
    success = False
    while not success:
        try:
            win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
            win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
            win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, bmp_data)
            win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
            success = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}. Retrying...")
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

So this

```
    cropped_image.save(buffer, format="JPEG", quality = 55)
    img_str = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(buffer.getvalue(), 9)).decode('utf-8')
```

slightly reduces the size of the image, but converting it to bmp format increases it back many times over, resulting in an image much larger than it was before. How to fix it?

Rest of the code:

```
def process_image(image):
    global counter
    width, height = image.size
    cropped_image = image.crop((0, 0, width - 5, height - 5))
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    print(f"[green]{counter}. [{current_time}][/green][yellow] {width}x{height}[/yellow] -> [green]{width - 5}x{height - 5}[/green]")
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    cropped_image.save(buffer, format="JPEG", quality = 55)
    img_str = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(buffer.getvalue(), 9)).decode('utf-8')
    counter += 1
    return img_str

def get_clipboard_image():
    success = False
    data = None
    while not success:
        try:
            win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
            if win32clipboard.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(win32clipboard.CF_DIB):
                data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB)
            elif win32clipboard.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT):
                data = None
            win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
            success = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}. Retrying...")
            time.sleep(0.1)

    return data

prev_image = None

while True:
    try:
        curr_data = get_clipboard_image()
        if curr_data is not None:
            curr_image = Image.open(BytesIO(curr_data))
            if prev_image is None or list(curr_image.getdata()) != list(prev_image.getdata()):
                img_str = process_image(curr_image)
                set_clipboard_image(img_str)
                prev_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(img_str))))

        time.sleep(0.5)
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```